# Выбрать ид строки с максимальным значением

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Дано, таблица:

```
table test  
id:integer  
x:integer  
y:integer
```

Данные в таблице

```
x y  
1 3  
2 4  
3 2  
4 5
```

Задача: 
найти такой X, для которого Y имеет максимальное значение, без подзапросов, `order by` и view. 
Т.е. в нашем примере максимальный "у"=5 значит нужно в итоге выбрать "х"=4.
Может как-то можно использовать JOIN с этой же таблицей?

Comment: Коррелированный подзапрос с `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Пока не представляю как он будет выглядеть

Comment: По-русски, но SQL-подобно, задача звучит так: "Выбрать X из одной записи таблицы, для которой не существует Y у другой записи таблицы больше, чем Y у этой записи". Переводим на английский, учитывая, что из одной копии таблицы можно взять только одну запись, так что нужны две копии таблицы, а не просто две записи, причёсываем полученное под требования SQL-синтаксиса - и получаем запрос.

Comment: Так oracle или mysql? Определитесь.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Спасибо Akina.
В итоге получилось решение.

```
SELECT t1.x   
FROM test t1   
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.y<t2.y   
WHERE t2.y IS null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать запросом следующего вида:

```
SELECT x FROM test WHERE y = (SELECT MAX(y) FROM test) ;
```

В PostgreSQL точно работает.

Comment: В условии сказано "без подзапросов". Незачет.

Answer (score 0):

В оракле (если у вас вдруг он) это можно сделать и без джойнов:

```
with t as (select 1 x, 3 y from dual union all
           select 2, 4 from dual union all
           select 3, 2 from dual union all
           select 4, 5 from dual)
select max(x) keep (dense_rank last order by y)
  from t;
```

[Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641).

Comment: Нужно одним селектом

Comment: Так это и есть один селект. Конструкция `with` здесь - это имитация вашей таблицы `test`. Запрос эквивалентен этому: `select max(x) keep (dense_rank last order by y) from test;` Просто в таком виде его удобнее запускать - не приходится создавать таблицу и заполнять ее данными.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, зачем вы [предлагаете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/326280) утвердить правку, в которой сносят сниппет?